# Why do I use sharedPreferences to putstring and cause Runtime error in camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to create a camera application. And get the image uri after capturing. Then I want to save that uri to SharedPreferences for the next time run and show at textView. But when I try to save it to SharedPreferences, I get run time error

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
Uri mCapturedImageURI;
Button camera;
TextView name;
TextView percent;
SharedPreferences prefs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    name= (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.name);
    percent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percent);
    String str="";
    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "com.example.camera", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    str = prefs.getString("image_name", "A");
    name.setText(str);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             String fileName = "temp.jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver()
                        .insert(
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                values);
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mCapturedImageURI); 
            startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if ((requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)
            && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null,
                null, null); 
        int column_index_data = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        prefs.edit().putString("image_name", capturedImageFilePath);
        name.setText(capturedImageFilePath);
    } 
}
```

Log file:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.camera/com.example.camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What line does the exception occur on? Can you add a stacktrace to your post?

Comment: It seems like I get the error when I add "  prefs.edit().putString("image_name", capturedImageFilePath);", if I try to delete it, the code work well but I can't take uri for next run! FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.camera, PID: 16499
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.camera/com.example.camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3836)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3886)

Comment: Try checking that `capturedImageFilePath` is not null before the call.

Comment: Oh, by your comment, I add if(capturedImageFilePath!=null), it work very well. But the capturedImagedFilePath is not null, so why does it happen :(

Comment: is onCreate always run before onActivityResult? otherwise `prefs` could be null.

Comment: I think so, because I have the CAMERA_QUEST before onActivityResult, even I don't have, the code can not get error, I think

Answer (score 0):

Add  if(capturedImageFilePath!=null) before prefs.edit().putString("image_name", capturedImageFilePath);